# WPF DataGrid Control Template

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controltemplate

I am trying to customize the WPF 4.0 DataGrid and need a listing of its control template (also the control template for the nested DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter - PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter). I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28VS.85%29.aspx) link with provides many control templates, but DataGrid is missing from the list! Is there any place where the control template for the latest WPF 4.0 DataGrid is published. I tried to get it using the following code, but it does not give me nested templates:

```
// Create an XmlWriter
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    ", NewLineOnAttributes = true };
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlSettings);

// Write the control template
ControlTemplate template = controlToExtract.Template;
XamlWriter.Save(template, writer);

// Write results to display
controlTemplate.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a link to download the [Default WPF Themes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=158252) from [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) on MSDN.  You can also use the [Reflector BamlViewer add-in](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer&referringTitle=Home) to read the themes directly from the assemblies.