# How can I convert a ControlTemplate to a XAML string in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, telerik

I'm working with a custom control for WPF called a [RadPane](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddocking-panes-radpane.html) (part of Telerik libraries), and I am observing some strange behavior when I undock and then redock a RadPane, and I suspect that its changing some templates dynamically, so I wanted to know if there is any way I could see the underlying XAML of a ControlTemplate? For example, a RadPane has the following member:

`RadPane.BottomTemplate` of type `ControlTemplate`.

How can I convert a `ControlTemplate` to a XAML string in WPF?

Comment: Have you looked at the Serialization? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-serialization-and-deserialization-using-xamlservices.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Create an XmlWriter
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    ", NewLineOnAttributes = true };
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlSettings);

XamlWriter.Save(RadPane.BottomTemplate, writer);
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548503/wpf-datagrid-control-template).

Comment: It doesn't give nested templates !!